# Gaming pc configuration

Tags: gaming, pc

I am trying to get the best feasible PC for gaming purposes.

My budget is 1000€, so I went to a shop that gave me a 1800€ PC configuration.
The one they provide is:
[image]

The price of the one with Nvidia 1660 is 1600€ with a price of 529€ only the GPU. The 3060 cost 200€ more.

As I have an screen that i do not want to change yet, asus `pb277q`, which works at 75Hz, I do not need more than this fps yet.

The problem of my budget is the GPU which is the thing that cost almost 50% of the total, so I thought to get a very powerful set of components for the rest of the PC and buy a `[GTX 1050TI 4GB]ASUS CERBERUS GEFORCE GTX 1050TI` that will cost me 175€.

This GPU price leaves 825€ to create the following config:

[image]

Later on, my intention is once the GPU prices came back to the normal one, buy a new one that fix the current bottleneck, and also a screen that works at 144Hz.

How do you see it? Any incompatibily that i do not know? Any improvement?

I checked the 1050, and seems to work at low cyberpunk at 40 fps. And battlefield V at 60fps. I will play this kind of games, so the bottleneck is hard, but its the only that I am able to pay right now. For me the current prices of GPU's are scam and unacceptable.

Comment: Questions that will help us answer: 1) How many monitors do you have? 2) What are their resolutions and refresh rates? 3) What games do you wish to play?

Comment: 4) How long do you plan on using the PC each day? 5) Are there any specific programs you want to use (e.g. CAD, Mining, Programming, Virtual Machines, Media Server, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

**Buget and build tips**
If you're not going to do any serious overclocking(with custom water loops or even below ambient) You can save a bit of money by going for a B550 motherboard a decent one is even good enough for a 5950x so the 5600x is fine on one.

Second, when going for an nvme drive try not to get a sata version. They are relatively slow for a miniscule cost saving. go for a decent to good nvme drive with a pci-e connection.

third, unless you plan to add a 3080 later on, a 750W power supply is on the high side, you might want to go for a 650 from a reputable brand.

**My advice**
If you plan to just play games. Go for an intel 11400F. The 5600x is a bit more powerful in gaming, but the real difference is in productivity work.
With the monitor you're running and your budget. I'm assuming that 11400 isn't going to have to support a 3080 any time soon. So there really isn't going to be that much difference in gaming performance between the 5600x and the 11400 at that point.
So if you don't need that productivity horsepower. I suggest going for the budget option.

Comment: Thanks @bobMeijer

I get a PCI-E and not a sata one finally :) 

I will consider the motherboard and the 11400F, the power supply is the 750w because I plan to add a 3080 later.

Comment: if you are planning on running a 3080 I would suggest also looking at the 11600, The 11400 is fine for a 1660 or even up to a  3060, but with a 3080 it'll be somewhat limited.

Answer (score 0):

I see incompatibilities in the bottom pc, because you can't connect a display. You can save some money on the motherboard by going with b550 and spend the money you have leftover on a simple graphics card you can still afford. You can also instead buy a last gen ryzen (3600) to save some more money so you can buy a better graphics card. I would also go with a kingston a2000 instead of kingston kc600 because it's faster and not much more expensive (maybe even cheaper)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare price to performance for parts, I highly recommend using https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/ and https://www.cpubenchmark.net/. While they aren't 100% accurate, they track pretty well for gaming performance and are very useful for when comparing Desktop Parts vs Laptop Parts. For game FPS performance there are many reviewers that regularly do benchmarks for games (such as Linus Tech Tips or Gamers Nexus).

If you have a budget of 1000€ or less, I would recommend getting a laptop. Laptops tend to be less prone to the price hikes than Desktops. At the time of writing this (June 2022) you would probably be pretty happy with a laptop with a Nvidia 3060 in it or something similar.